# understanding parsing the route path variable of node-express route.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why does this give me 404-NotFound?

```
var test = require('./routes/test');
app.use('/test', test);
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    //res.render('/test', { title: 'test' });
    res.send('respond with a TEST resource');
});
```

where this given me what is expected?

```
var test = require('./routes/test');
app.use('/test', test);
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    //res.render('/test', { title: 'test' });
    res.send('respond with a TEST resource');
});
```

In either case res.send() & res.render() behave alike.  The first response is 404-NotFound.  The second is what you want to see.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is what I'm understanding correct?

The `route.get('/', ... )` in this case really means the get of `http://site/test` because the test.js file is in a file `routes/test.js`.
So in this case the `'\'` of the `get()` is to relative to the root of `/test`.